# How do I create a sticky menu?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a [sticky menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cga74.png). I tried several times and here's my last [try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmW4F.jpg):

Here is my code that I've tried:

```css
.nav-menu-holder li a.wpfm-menu-link .wpfm-icon-block {
    color: #fff;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 34px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.nav-menu-holder li a.wpfm-menu-link .wpfm-icon-block i {
    line-height: unset;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.nav-menu-holder li a.wpfm-menu-link .wpfm-menu-name-tooltip-wrap, .nav-menu-holder li a.wpfm-menu-link .wpfm-menu-name-tooltip-wrap, .nav-menu-holder li a.wpfm-menu-link .wpfm-menu-name-tooltip-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    left: 55px;
    top: -30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: -moz-max-content;
    width: -webkit-max-content;
    width: max-content;
    background: #724fc7;
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.nav-menu-holder li a.wpfm-menu-link .wpfm-menu-name-tooltip-wrap:before, .nav-menu-holder li a.wpfm-menu-link .wpfm-menu-name-tooltip-wrap:before, .nav-menu-holder li a.wpfm-menu-link .wpfm-menu-name-tooltip-wrap:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -6px;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border-right: 6px solid #724fc7;
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-menu-holder">
            <ul>
                <li class="wpfm-active-nav" data-li-key="1">
                    <a title="" class="wpfm-menu-link" href="#div-1" rel=" ">
                        <span class="wpfm-icon-block ">
                        <i class="dashicons dashicons-admin-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span class="wpfm-menu-name-tooltip-wrap">
                            <span class="name wpfm-menu-name">Home</span>
                        </span>
                    </a>    
                </li>
                <li data-li-key="1">
                    <a title="" class="wpfm-menu-link" href="#div-1" rel=" ">
                        <span class="wpfm-icon-block ">
                        <i class="dashicons dashicons-admin-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span class="wpfm-menu-name-tooltip-wrap">
                            <span class="name wpfm-menu-name">Home</span>
                        </span>
                    </a>    
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `position : fixed` is what you are looking for

Comment: thank you for your help my menu is fixed but my problem in design css.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the navbar stick with javascript
1). Add CSS

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

*If you add this class to the HTML then the navbar will be on the top
so we have to add it when the user scrolls. For that, we have to
2). Add javaScript

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the navbar
var navbar = document.getElementByClassName("nav-menu-holder");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help my menu is fixed but my problem in design css.